# Erro ao comparar duas Strings C

Tags: c, string

Introduzo na linha de comandos um valor. Que esteja no vetor binário. Mas caso não esteja devolve à mensagem do `printf`. Mas o meu problema é que sempre entra no ciclo `if`, independentemente seja binário ou não.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ex02.h"

int main(){

 char binario [50][100]={"0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"};

 char nome [0][10];

 int contador=0;

  printf("Insira um valor\n");
  scanf("%s",nome[0]);

while(nome[contador]!='\0'){

   if ( strcmp(nome[0], binario[contador]) !=0 )
        {
            printf("Base inicial invalida");
            break;
        }

        contador++;
 } 

 return 0;
```

Comment: Tem certeza que o enunciado é esse? O código não produz o que está no enunciado nem de perto.

Comment: Seria bom [edit] e acrescentar exemplos de que dados você entrou no teste, que resultado deu, e que resultados você espera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código tem várias falhas e não faz nem de perto o que está pedindo na pergunta. Vou tentar consertar.

Note que as declarações dos *arrays* podem ser feitos no tamanho que eles são necessários. Isso dá mais eficiência. Então `binario` só precisa 16 elementos e cada um deles só precisa 5 bytes (4 caracteres + o terminador). `nome` só precisa do *array* de caracteres, não tem porque existir outra dimensão. Nenhuma dimensão pode ter tamanho 0.

Eu preferi usar o `for`, embora o `while` não esteja errado.

O `if` está bem errado. Para saber se n]ao achou um texto dentro da lista previamente definida tem que analisar todos os itens. O código atual está analisando o primeiro item, se não é igual ele termina o laço e encerra a busca. Ou seja esse código exige que todos sejam igual para funcionar. Não é o que quer. A solução é deixar pesquisar até o fim, ou até achar um deles. Se achar um não tem porque continuar pesquisando, basta um para satisfazer o que deseja.

Mas como saber se não achou? É simples, se ele passar por todos e nunca sair do laço forçadamente é que nunca achou. Para saber que isso ocorreu é só verificar se o contador percorreu todos os elementos e alcançou 16. Mesmo que ache no último elemento o `break` forçaria a saída e o último incremento não seria feito, aí o contador valeria 15.

Tem outros problema no código que eu não vou tratar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char binario[16][5] = {"0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"};
    char nome[10];
    printf("Insira um valor\n");
    scanf("%s", nome);
    int contador = 0;
    for (; contador < 16 && strcmp(nome, binario[contador]) != 0; contador++);
    if (contador == 16) printf("Base inicial invalida"); //essa mensagem não faz sentido com o enunciado
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yPMrDN). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/txnwjlxi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/FindNumber.c).

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com sua explanação, voce deve analisar a lógica de seu código para funcionar conforme as regras de funcionamento de cada API. No caso de strcmp temos a seguinte regra de operação:

```
int strcmp(
   const char *string1,
   const char *string2 
);
Return Value
The return value for each of these functions indicates the ordinal relation of string1 to string2.
Value Relationship of string1 to string2
< 0   string1 is less than string2
  0   string1 is identical to string2
> 0   string1 is greater than string2
```

Portanto seu código entra no IF porque sempre está retornado valor diferente de zero, já que em nehuma comparação localiza um valor identico.